# I dont know how to program one part of a word guess program

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a guess a letter game in python. the program chooses a random word from a file and the user has the amount of letters to guess the letters to the word. There is one part I am having trouble coding. I need to display the word as dashes and after every guess change the dashed word to include the correctly guessed letters in their corresponding position. So the output looks something like this.

Welcome to Guess a Letter!

### Your word has 10 letters
You have 10 incorrect guesses.
Here is the word:

Enter a letter: e
Awe, shucks. You missed with that letter
Enter a letter: a
You got a hit! Here's what the word looks like now:
-------a-a
Enter a letter: o
Awe, shucks. You missed with that letter
Enter a letter: u
Awe, shucks. You missed with that letter
Enter a letter: i
You got a hit! Here's what the word looks like now:
---i---a-a
Enter a letter: y
You got a hit! Here's what the word looks like now:
-y-i---a-a
Enter a letter: t
You got a hit! Here's what the word looks like now:
-y-i-t-ata
Enter a letter: l
You got a hit! Here's what the word looks like now:
ly-i-t-ata
Enter a letter: s
You got a hit! Here's what the word looks like now:
lysist-ata
Enter a letter: r
You got a hit! Here's what the word looks like now:
lysistrata
You won!
Great job!

so here is what i have so far

```
import random
def pick_word_from_file():
    '''Read a file of words and return one word at random'''
    file = open("wordlist.txt", 'r')
    words = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    global word #globalizes the variable "word"
    word = random.choice(words).strip("\n")
    global guesses
    guesses = len(word) #number of guesses user has according to number of letters
    print(word)

def dashed_word():  #this function turns the word into dashes
    global hidden_word #globalizes the variable "hidden_word"
    hidden_word = ""
    for letter in word: #this for loop changes all the letters of the word to dashes
        if letter != " ":
            hidden_word = hidden_word + "-"
    print(hidden_word)
    list(hidden_word)

def game_intro():   #introduces word game rules
    print("Welcome to Guess a Word!\n")
    print("Your word has",len(word),"letters")
    print("You have",len(word),"incorrect guesses.")
    print("Only guess with lower case letters please!")
   
def game(): #this is the main games function

    global guess
    
    
        for letter in range(len(word)):
            guess = input("Please enter a lowercase letter as your guess: ")    #asks user for lowercase letter as their guess
            new_hidden_word = ''
            random_int = 0
            int(random_int)
            for i in range(len(word)):
                if guess == word[i:i+1]:
                    print("Lucky guess!")
                    print(guess, "is in position", i+1)
                
               
                    hidden_word[i] = guess
                    hidden_word.join(' ')

                    print(hidden_word)
                    random_int = 1
            if random_int == 0:
                print("Unlucky")
           
                
                     

def main(): #this runs all the functions in order
    pick_word_from_file()
    game_intro()
    dashed_word()
    game()

main()
```

Just need help with what is in the game() function

Comment: Please copy and paste your code. No images, please

Comment: my bad, I changed it so if you still want to help that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm sorry I sounded so mean earlier! I didn't mean to be so insensitive. This isn't a direct answer to your question, but there's a really good book out there called "Invent Your Own Computer Games with Python" by Al Sweigart. In the book, he covers how to write a guessing game and hangman along with lots of other cool stuff like pygame, so I definitely recommend it! Good luck with solving your problem:)

Answer (score 0):

Since strings a immutable, I would use a list to keep track of the guesses and then transfer that to a string in order to print it out. Here is your code modified to reflect those changes :

```
import random

def pick_word_from_file():
    '''Read a file of words and return one word at random'''
    file = open("wordlist.txt", 'r')
    words = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    global word #globalizes the variable "word"
    word = random.choice(words).strip("\n")
    global guesses
    guesses = len(word) #number of guesses user has according to number of letters
    print(word)

def dashed_word():  #this function turns the word into dashes
    global hidden_word #globalizes the variable "hidden_word"
    hidden_word = [] 
    for letter in word: #this for loop changes all the letters of the word to dashes
        if letter != " ":
            hidden_word.append ("-")
    print_out = ''
    print(print_out.join (hidden_word))

def game_intro():   #introduces word game rules
    print("Welcome to Guess a Word!\n")
    print("Your word has",len(word),"letters")
    print("You have",len(word),"incorrect guesses.")
    print("Only guess with lower case letters please!")
   
def game(): #this is the main games function

    global guess
    for letter in range(len(word)):
        guess = input("Please enter a lowercase letter as your guess: ")    #asks user for lowercase letter as their guess
        new_hidden_word = ''
        random_int = 0
        int(random_int)
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if guess == word[i:i+1]:
                print("Lucky guess!")
                print(guess, "is in position", i+1)
                hidden_word[i] = guess
                print_out = ''
                print(print_out.join (hidden_word))
                random_int = 1
        if random_int == 0:
            print("Unlucky")

def main(): #this runs all the functions in order
    pick_word_from_file()
    game_intro()
    dashed_word()
    game()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I group all functions into one so we don't need to declare global variables. I also add something:

- use .lower() to accept uppercase input
- a statement telling user how many guesses left
- win and lose condition

```
import random

def game():
    # pick_word_from_file()
    # using with to close the file automatically
    with open("wordlist.txt") as f:
        wordlist = f.readlines()
        word = random.choice(wordlist).strip("\n")

    # game_intro()
    print("Welcome to Guess a Word!\n")
    print("Your word has", len(word), "letters")
    # why we need to say incorrect guesses from the start?
    # print("You have", len(word), "incorrect guesses.")

    # dashed_word()
    # use a list to save letters because string is immutable
    hidden_word = ["-" for w in word]
    print("".join(hidden_word))

    # number of guesses equal to length of word
    for guesses in range(len(word)):
        # tell user how many guesses left
        print(f"You have {len(word) - guesses} guesses left.")
        # use .lower() so user can also input uppercase letter
        guess = input("Please enter a letter as your guess: ").lower()

        change = False
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if word[i] == guess:
                hidden_word[i] = guess
                change = True
        if change:
            print("You got a hit! Here's what the word looks like now:")
            print("".join(hidden_word))
        else:
            print("Awe, shucks. You missed with that letter.")
            
        if "".join(hidden_word) == word:
            print("You won! Great job!")
            break
    # you lose when you are out of guesses
    else:
        print("You lose.")

game()
```

Output:

```
"""
Welcome to Guess a Word!

Your word has 10 letters
----------
You have 10 guesses left.
Please enter a letter as your guess: E
Awe, shucks. You missed with that letter.
You have 9 guesses left.
Please enter a letter as your guess: A
You got a hit! Here's what the word looks like now:
-------a-a
You have 8 guesses left.
Please enter a letter as your guess: O
Awe, shucks. You missed with that letter.
You have 7 guesses left.
Please enter a letter as your guess: U
Awe, shucks. You missed with that letter.
You have 6 guesses left.
Please enter a letter as your guess: I
You got a hit! Here's what the word looks like now:
---i---a-a
You have 5 guesses left.
Please enter a letter as your guess: Y
You got a hit! Here's what the word looks like now:
-y-i---a-a
You have 4 guesses left.
Please enter a letter as your guess: T
You got a hit! Here's what the word looks like now:
-y-i-t-ata
You have 3 guesses left.
Please enter a letter as your guess: L
You got a hit! Here's what the word looks like now:
ly-i-t-ata
You have 2 guesses left.
Please enter a letter as your guess: S
You got a hit! Here's what the word looks like now:
lysist-ata
You have 1 guesses left.
Please enter a letter as your guess: R
You got a hit! Here's what the word looks like now:
lysistrata
You won! Great job!
"""
```